# Is it necessary to show that the complement of a set belongs to a topology to call it a closed set?

Tags: general-topology

I am preparing for my exam on Point Set Topology and in the lectures provided by my teacher, I have seen that he has stated the given below example with its solution as mentioned.

> **Ex 2.2.** Determine if $[a, b]$ is open, closed, or clopen set in the topology $\tau = \{\emptyset, \mathbb R, (-n, n) | n = 1, 2, 3,\ldots\}$ on $\mathbb R$, where $0 < a < b$.

**Solution:** Here $[a, b] \not\in \tau = \{\emptyset, \mathbb R, (-n, n) | n = 1, 2, 3,\ldots\}$, so $[a, b]$ is not open in this topology. $[a, b]^c =(-\infty, a) \cup (b, \infty) \not\in\tau$ so $[a, b]$ is not a closed subset of $\mathbb R$ in this topology.

---

Let's say the set $X=\{1, 2, 3\}$ has a topology $\tau = \{\emptyset, X, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{1, 2\}\}$.

Here, the complement of $\{2\}$ is $\{1, 3\}$. So isn't $\{1, 3\}$ a closed set of the topological space $(X, \tau)$, since the definition of a closed set states, "A set is said to be a closed subset of a topological space $(X, \tau)$ if it is the complement of an open set of $X$."?

If yes, then why my teacher has stated in the example above that $[a, b]$ is not a closed subset of $\mathbb R$ in the topology $\tau = \{\emptyset, \mathbb R, (-n, n) | n = 1, 2, 3,\ldots\}$ on $\mathbb R$, because $[a, b]^c =(-\infty, a) \cup (b, \infty) \not\in\tau$?

Is it necessary for the complement of an open set of topology to exist within the same topology in which the open set lies to be a closed set?

Comment: Yes. {1,3} is closed in that topology. Is that your only question?

Comment: @BenjaminWang If yes, then why my teacher has stated in the example above that [a, b] is not a closed subset of R in the topology τ={Φ, R, (-n, n)|n=1,2,3, ...} on R because [a, b]c = (-∞, a) ∪ (b, ∞) ∉ τ={Φ, R, (-n, n)|n=1,2,3, ...}?

Comment: I mean, it is true that $[a,b]^c$ is not open in the first topology you gave, no?

Comment: Is it necessary for the complement of an open set of topology to exist within the same topology in which the open set lies to be a closed set?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thanks, @JoséCarlosSantos. I was looking for it.

Comment: In any topology, the complement of a closed set is open and vice versa. Just because $[0,1]$ is closed in the standard topology doesn't mean it is closed in every topology.

Comment: Note the "$\notin$" symbol. The author is saying the complement is not in the topology.

Comment: @SharjeelFaiq I think you overcomplicate things. Note that $(Y^c)^c=Y$ for any subset $Y\subseteq X$. Therefore a subset $A\subseteq X$ is closed if and only if $A^c$ is open. And therefore your teacher showed that $[a,b]$ is not closed by showing that $[a,b]^c$ is not open.

Comment: @freakish, I got you. Thanks. How can I close this question or marked is as answered?